# Is there any way to get client's Computer Name at the server side using client Socket connection?(For Example :-Windows-PC)

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

```
Socket clientsocket = serverSock.accept();

String clientIP = clientsocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

String clientName = clientsocket.getInetAddress().getHostName();
```

But `clientIP` and `clientName` both returns same value (like 192.168.173.46).

Comment: What do you get if you try `clientsocket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName()`?

Comment: @Ihsan   clientsocket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName() also returns same like 192.168.173.46   .

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on the Oracle website I assume that you have a bad DNS setup. The following documentation is for the `getHostName()` method:

> public String getHostName() Gets the host name for this IP address. If
>   this InetAddress was created with a host name, this host name will be
>   remembered and returned; otherwise, a reverse name lookup will be
>   performed and the result will be returned based on the system
>   configured name lookup service. If a lookup of the name service is
>   required, call getCanonicalHostName.
>
> If there is a security manager, its checkConnect method is first
>   called with the hostname and -1 as its arguments to see if the
>   operation is allowed. If the operation is not allowed, it will return
>   the textual representation of the IP address.
>
> Returns: the host name for this IP address, or if the operation is not
>   allowed by the security check, the textual representation of the IP
>   address. See Also: getCanonicalHostName(),
>   SecurityManager.checkConnect(java.lang.String, int)

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName())

I do not know how you could fix this, but you could try adding a hostname manually in your hosts file.